# Do women statistically have better multitasking ability than men?

Tags: gender

I hear this very often, while woman can do several things at a time. If this is true, what are the *qualifications* that make woman capable of doing several things at once?

A quick Google search returned an obviously popular book;

[image]

However, I haven't read it and I'm not planning to. Plans may change if this gets interesting though.

Are there any evidence that support the idea/ theory?

Comment: But don't you clearly see examples of men doing more than one thing at a time? What does this even mean? I've eaten while watching tv, for instance.

Comment: So your position seems to be "Here is a book which answers my question, but I don't want to read it." Why not?

Comment: I can't judge the book by it's cover, however if I would read the book I would only get the authors point of view.

Comment: @Whirlwin: I edited the title to make the question more well-defined and answerable; I hope without changing what you intended to ask. Feel free to roll back if you disapprove.

Comment: I've heard that in families where men take care of the family while their wife's at work these skills are swapped (i.e. the man multi-task and the woman find it hard to do so). I don't have a reference for it, but it might help you in digging for data.

Comment: @Oddthinking I think it's pretty okay that he doesn't want to read a book which has two untruthful (or at least exaggerated) statements in the title already.

Comment: Anecdotally, it appears to me that none are capable of doing more than one thing (where at least one of the tasks is something complex) at a time with much success.  Some just choose to ignore their failures...  :-)

Comment: @Ruben Exactly. The second premise (women never stop talking) is false as well: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/do-women-talk-more-than-men

Comment: @Whirlwin, unless, of course, the author provided cites to the relevant scientific literature...

Comment: @Ruben, that's begging the question. They are the claims being assessed. If you start by assuming that they are false, and use that to decide that you don't need to consider any evidence that supports them, then you are going to fallaciously find that they are unsupported by the evidence, and therefore false!

Comment: (Do I need to mention that I suspect that the claims ARE substantially false, but I am trying to be a skeptic, not a cynic, which means keeping an open mind?)

Comment: @Oddthinking I think prodding someone on a Skeptics website to read a book by the Pease's smells a little like "learn first, then criticize". Also, the cover makes two extreme statements (*only*, *never*) which can be refuted by two single everyday observations. If this book cites its sources and these sources actually support their outrageous cover claims I'd be surprised. So for now, I think it's okay to assume that they're wrong and look for scientific literature directly. If that showed a dearth of evidence I might consider looking at their sources (any?).

Comment: @Ruben, thanks for your comment. I confess I haven't understood it, but I'd like to. Are you saying "learn first, then criticize" is inappropriate? How so? As in the Courtier's Reply? Making extreme statements on the cover to sell books, with softer statements inside isn't uncommon. This question originally came  across to me as "A book? How tiresome. Will someone read this for me and tell me what it says?"

Comment: @Oddthinking: I just googled the question (as is was written earlier) and the book showed up. Maybe I shouldn't have included the image. It was just because I thought people would've never heard about the *theory* earlier, not because I know the author nor the book, but because it showed to be popular.

Comment: @Oddthinking @Whirlwin Apparently there was no laziness involved here. I think Skeptics should have a friendly tone and someone who provides a reference to show that a claim is "widely repeated" shouldn't be accused because he doesn't want to read the book which would then probably not be considered evidence in this very place. I don't mean to be as drastic as "The Courtier's Reply" (had to look it up). I think there's some "evidence" that's not worth giving a first-hand look (such as the Zeitgeist movie and, to my mind, the Pease books). Also, the book isn't available for free.

Comment: I added a new answer in may, nobody seem to have read it. I had like some opinion (since it is different from the accepted one).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Edit: Now there's some evidence for this idea

I thought I'd come back to this question, because I wasn't really satisfied with what the literature yielded back then and the paper that Peters mentioned (there had only been a press release) has come out.
[Stoet, O'Connor, Conner, & Laws (2013)](http://www.biomedcentral.com/2050-7283/1/18/abstract) looked at this and found some evidence for the idea.

Quoting from their abstract

> ### Background
>
> There seems to be a common belief that women are better in
>   multi-tasking than men, but there is practically no scientific
>   research on this topic. Here, we tested whether women have better
>   multi-tasking skills than men.
>
> ### Methods
>
> In Experiment 1, we compared performance of 120 women and 120
>   men in a computer-based task-switching paradigm. In Experiment 2, we
>   compared a different group of 47 women and 47 men on
>   "paper-and-pencil" multi-tasking tests.
>
> ### Results
>
> In Experiment 1, both men and women performed more slowly when
>   two tasks were rapidly interleaved than when the two tasks were
>   performed separately. Importantly, this slow down was significantly
>   larger in the male participants (Cohen’s d = 0.27). In an everyday
>   multi-tasking scenario (Experiment 2), men and women did not differ
>   significantly at solving simple arithmetic problems, searching for
>   restaurants on a map, or answering general knowledge questions on the
>   phone, but women were significantly better at devising strategies for
>   locating a lost key (Cohen’s d = 0.49).
>
> ### Conclusions
>
> Women outperform men in these multi-tasking paradigms, but
>   the near lack of empirical studies on gender differences in
>   multitasking should caution against making strong generalisations.
>   Instead, we hope that other researchers will aim to replicate and
>   elaborate on our findings.

--- end edit

## Old answer

#### No, there is no such evidence.

Apparently there didn't use to be much evidence against it either, but I found two recent studies by Noemi Peters ([2010](http://www.tinbergen.nl/files/theses/mphil079.pdf), [2011](http://www.economists.nl/files/20110223-MultitaskingTI.pdf)).

First I did a search on "sex
differences" multitasking and similar
terms, but I could only find a dodgy
study in support and not much
well-received publications in the
field anyway. Apparently Ms Peters found the
same dearth in the literature. The fun part:
I found her publications by looking [who had
cited the Pease book](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=2183100993815825692&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=1,5&hl=en) :-)

> I searched extensively for peer-reviewed scientiﬁc publications that
>   examine gender differences in multitasking ability, but the closest I
>   could ﬁnd is Criss (2006) and Havel (2004), which are manuscripts that
>   are made available online at  the website of the National
>   Undergraduate Research Clearinghouse. Both examined subjects who had
>   to perform some  speciﬁed tasks while tallying keywords from a
>   song/story.
>   **None of them found gender differences** in productivity when  multitasking, but Criss (2006) found that women were better at
>   accuracy. Nonetheless, we do not know whether the ﬁndings can be
>   attributed to multitasking as **none** of them **had a control
>   group**. Besides, some British newspapers reported  recently about an
>   experiment that supports the view that women are better (see Gray,
>   2010), but when I contacted the lead researcher, Professor Keith Laws,
>   it turned out that there is not even a working paper yet that I could
>   discuss here.

Her evidence to the contrary wasn't published
in peer reviewed journals, so if somebody
has something stronger, better pay attention to that instead.

#### From the abstract of her dissertation:

> The view that women are
>   better at multitasking is widely held,
>   however **there is no scientiﬁc 
>   evidence supporting it**. This
>   experiment examines whether there are
>   gender differences in multitasking
>   ability and in the inclination to
>   multitask. To this end, I conduct an
>   experiment with  three treatments: one
>   where subjects have to execute two
>   tasks sequentially, one where subjects
>   are forced to multitask with the two
>   tasks, and one where they can choose
>   freely how to organize  their work.
>   The results of the third treatment
>   indicate that there is **no gender
>   difference in the inclination to
>   multitask**. As far as multitasking
>   ability is concerned, I do ﬁnd a
>   **gender difference but it is contrary
>   to the widely held beliefs**: point
>   estimates indicate that men perform
>   better both under forced and voluntary
>   multitasking. This gender difference
>   reaches statistical signiﬁcance in
>   case of voluntary multitasking.

Comment: "I searched extensively for peer-reviewed scientiﬁc publications that examine gender differences in multitasking ability, but the closest I could ﬁnd is Criss (2006) and Havel (2004)"         The first link on [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=multitasking+gender&as_sdt=0%2C6&as_ylo=&as_vis=0) seems relevant.

Comment: @Mud I found this too. It's only a conference proceeding, however, so, not peer-reviewed. It's also paywalled for me, so I can't have a deeper look.

Comment: It is a bit confusing to highlight "None of the found gender differences", when the statement only applies to productivity, not accuracy

Comment: @Casebash It's worthless anyhow, because they did not have a control group and weren't published in PR journals. But my thinking when I highlighted that bit was probably that accuracy doesn't count for much (if it worked, you'd multi-task to save time => productivity, not to obtain higher accuracy).

Comment: @ApisGirl I saw your edit that Sklivvz rejected. That's a little bit interesting, maybe you can upload the conference proceeding somewhere. 
I think I heard of peer-reviewed research into this in the meanwhile, probably my search terms are just way off, one probably should look at the executive functions lit. especially task switching.

Comment: Surprised that you got so many more votes than me. Is it because of the study results?

Comment: @Zonata If I was an optimist, I'd say that the Stoet et al study has larger sample sizes and relates better to folk psychology. But probably the truth is closer to: 1. because this answer was already at the top 2. people like having their expectations confirmed 3. people dislike uncertainty. I think there is no clear answer to this question yet.

Comment: @Ruben You are probably correct. I agree there is no definitive answer on this.

Answer (score 6):

The [Straight Dope](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/3078/are-women-better-at-multitasking-than-men) wrote an article on this:

> A lot of the cognitive research on sex differences in multitasking,
>   unfortunately, has fixated on simultasking. The results have been all
>   over the place — some showing that men do better, some women, some
>   neither. Few of the studies I’ve seen compare the results of
>   simultasking against a control group of unitaskers, that is, people
>   doing just one thing. My guess is that, for intellectually demanding
>   work, unitaskers do way better than simultaskers of either sex...
>
> Research and common sense suggest that the only way to do two tasks
>   competently at the same time is to make sure at least one of them
>   requires minimal brainpower, for example folding laundry while on the
>   phone. A reasonable surmise is that women’s reputation as superior
>   multitaskers stems partly from the fact that they’re
>   disproportionately burdened with mindless household chores that can
>   readily be done simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

There has been some changes since the OP asked this question and at least one relevant research paper has tried to provide a new answer to this question. According to  study [this](http://pss.sagepub.com/content/24/4/514.full.pdf+html) (Mäntylä T. 2013) published in one of the top ten peer reviewed journal of psychology:

### Yes there is evidence... but men seems better at it

(emphasis is from me)

> The second main finding of Experiment 1 was that males (mean
>   proportion correct = .85) outperformed females (mean proportion
>   correct =  .74) at multitasking, as indexed by accuracy in the counter
>   task, F(1, 70) = 6.25, ηp 2  = .08, p < .01.
>
> As shown in Figure 1, **the gender difference in accuracy favored men by about 10%**
>   across the three counter tasks. This  difference was not due to a trade-off
>   between accuracy in the counter tasks and in the background
>   (name-back) task, given that **both men and women identified about 38%**
>    **of the targets** in the name-back task (with no differences in false
>   alarms). Furthermore, gender differences in counter-task accuracy 
>   were not related to differences in monitoring frequency (F <  1).
>   Females (mean proportion correct = .52) performed somewhat better than
>   men (mean proportion correct = .48) in the  letter-memory task, but
>   this difference was not reliable (F < 1).

The second experiment demonstrated another interesting fact:

> Experiment 2 provided additional support for this hypothesis by
>   showing that gender differences in multitasking (and spatial ability)
>   were eliminated among females who were in the menstrual, but not the
>   luteal, phase of their menstrual cycle.

### Limitations

The author is aware of some limit of his experiments. Most of them are related to the assumption that multitasking involve spatial abilities. I extracted the most interesting part of the discussion, but refer to the original paper for better understanding of their impacts. (again, emphasis is from me)

> [...] it was necessary to use (gender-fair) test conditions in which
>   the role of **domain-specific skills and experiences were minimized**.
>   Furthermore, although most everyday multitasking may involve a great
>   deal of spatiotemporal processing, it is reasonable to assume that
>   these demands are domain specific. A central assumption of the
>   spatiotemporal hypothesis introduced here is that gender differences
>   in multitasking are expected when the demands on temporal coordination
>   are relatively high. In most dual-task conditions, **these demands are
>   low and less dependent on spatial abilities** than are multiple tasks
>   that may require coordination of a complex pattern of temporal
>   contingencies. This *line of reasoning is also consistent with
>   evidence from earlier studies showing **no gender-related differences** in
>   dual-task conditions*.
>
> [...] Another limitation of the study is that both experiments
>   involved relatively **restricted time frames** and **predictable
>   target events** (in the counter tasks). The term multitasking is a
>   loosely defined construct that covers a wide spectrum of activities
>   and time frames. Multitasking in some conditions may require very
>   narrow deadlines (e.g., air traffic control), whereas other types of
>   multitasking (e.g., household activities) may impose **lower demands
>   on spatiotemporal** processing because of more-generous time windows.
>   It is reasonable to assume that, like most goal-directed tasks,
>   everyday multitasking reflects different mixtures of task-independent
>   cognitive functions (e.g., components of executive functioning and
>   spatial processing) and more domain-specific skills and strategies.
>   From this perspective, individual differences in multitasking should
>   be considered in relative terms, given that **some conditions may show
>   reduced  or even reversed gender differences because of task-specific 
>   constraints and strategies**.

Mäntylä T., *Gender Differences in Multitasking Reflect Spatial Ability*,
Psychological Science, April 1, 2013 24: 514-520

Answer (score 0):

**This is a widely held belief, but it is not (at this point) supported by evidence.**

Here is the conclusion of a 2015 peer-reviewed study published in Plos One:

> Taken together, we found strong evidence supporting a gender
>   stereotype in multitasking abilities: A considerable proportion of
>   participants from a variety of countries believe that women are better
>   at multitasking than men. This stereotype exists despite the absence
>   of strong empirical data which would justify such a belief. Further
>   research might resolve whether there truly are no gender differences
>   in multitasking abilities or whether previous research just did not
>   look at the right tasks and paradigms.

The study assessed the prevalence of this belief:

> Results showed that overall more than 50% of the participants believed
>   in gender differences in multitasking abilities. Of those who believed
>   in gender differences, a majority of 80% believed that women were
>   better at multitasking.

The study also researched how people of both sexes assessed their own multitasking capability. The results appear to contradict the previous belief:

> With respect to their own multitasking abilities, there
>   was—interestingly—no difference between male and female participants.
>   In other words, the very same sample of participants who showed a
>   strong belief in gender differences in multitasking abilities did not
>   show any gender difference when asked to judge their own abilities.
>   However, females reported to spend 45 minutes more multitasking per
>   day than males.

The study includes a review of the existing evidence supporting the belief yields mixed results:

> Taken together, the evidence from cognitive psychology on gender
>   differences in multitasking is mixed, i.e. sometimes men are better at
>   multitasking and sometimes women are better, but the size of the
>   gender difference is usually very small. In addition, often no
>   differences between men and women are reported at all. Thus, it
>   appears questionable that a potential stereotype on gender differences
>   in multitasking abilities is based on findings from cognitive
>   psychology.

Finally, a plausible explanation is provided by the authors:

> Alternatively, it might be that participants confused or equated the
>   amount of time spend multitasking and the proficiency in multitasking.
>   Our own study showed that women reported to multitask more, and female
>   as well as male participants thought that women do spend more time
>   multitasking.

The study is freely available online and makes an interesting read.

André J. Szameitat et al., “Women Are Better Than Men”–Public Beliefs on Gender Differences and Other Aspects in Multitasking, Plos One, October 19, 2015

https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0140371